# Overriding description method in NSObject on swift

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm getting one compiler error when I try to build one object in my xcode project. This is the code:

```
import UIKit

class Rectangulo: NSObject {

    var ladoA : Int
    var ladoB : Int
    var area: Int {
        get {
            return ladoA*ladoB
        }
    }

    init (ladoA:Int,ladoB:Int) {

        self.ladoA = ladoA
        self.ladoB = ladoB
    }

    func description() -> NSString {
                return "El area es \(area)"
    }
}
```

The error in compilation time is:

```
Rectangulo.swift:26:10: Method 'description()' with Objective-C selector 'description' conflicts with getter for 'description' from superclass 'NSObject' with the same Objective-C selector
```

What I need to do to override this function without issues?

Comment: Do you need it to be subclass of NSObject? If you dont need it then you wont have the problem with overriding description.

Comment: Yes, I need, is an example

Comment: http://swiftstub.com/803133613/ This works perfectly ...

Comment: I'm starting to think that is a problem in my configuration

Comment: Do you still get error: "Cannot override with stored property description"?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

- `description` is a (computed) property of `NSObjectProtocol`, not a method.
- Its Swift view returns a `String`, not `NSString`.
- Since you are overriding a property of a superclass, you must specify `override` explicitly.

Together:

```
// main.swift:
import Foundation

class Rectangulo: NSObject {

    var ladoA : Int
    var ladoB : Int
    var area: Int {
        get {
            return ladoA*ladoB
        }
    }

    init (ladoA:Int,ladoB:Int) {

        self.ladoA = ladoA
        self.ladoB = ladoB
    }

    override var description : String {
        return "El area es \(area)"
    }
}

let r = Rectangulo(ladoA: 2, ladoB: 3)
print(r) // El area es 6
```

Comment: With this code, I get the following issue in compilation time: First, Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'. Resolved, I get "Cannot override with stored property description".

Comment: @jgd: Which Xcode version are you using? I have tested the code with Xcode 6.3.2 and it worked as expected.

Comment: @jgd: I have updated the answer with the full code. It compiles and runs without problems for me.

Comment: I have to add I'm calling to println(r) in viewController.swift, but I don't know if this is relevant (ios newbie). Is a Single View project.

Comment: @jgd: You can execute statements (like println) only from *within methods* (main.swift is the only exception).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81123/discussion-between-jgd-and-martin-r).

Comment: in Xcode 7.3.1, I was required to match the superclass's public accessibility with "override public var description : String {...}", but it worked after that.